# Using MVVM with Frame

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I want to make frame invisible when changed text on my entry.So far i tried with 
.And make visible when text not changed.

**My MVVM class**

```
public  class MVVM { 
  public  bool IsVisible = true;
    public bool IsShowFrame
    {
        get => IsVisible;
        set
        {
            IsVisible = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**xaml**

```
<Entry x:Name="entryName"  TextChanged="justchill_TextChanged"/>
<Frame  BackgroundColor="Gray" Margin="10" x:Name="FramesName" IsVisible="{Binding  IsVisible}" />
```

But i am not sure how to implant text changed here for entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really confused by the code, but i think I know what you're trying to do..

On your **MVVM CLASS** you'll need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. To do this, you'll need to add the required namespace(s), Eventhandler, AND the 'trigger'. To keep this simple, i'm going to start your class from scratch - you can manually add these parts to your existing code if you need to.

### Part 1 - Getting your MVVM class properly setup

Step 1: Add the required **using statements** to the top of the page:

```
using System.ComponentModel;   
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```

Step 2:Add INotifyPropertyChanged - you will get an immediate 'error' - ignore it for now, we're not done.

```
 public class MVVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

 }
```

Step 3: Add the EventHandler (which fixes the error from step 2):

```
 public class MVVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 }
```

Step 4: Add the Trigger:

```
 public class MVVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 }
```

With all of this added, you are NOW ready to start adding your properties. I've made a few changes based on what i'm assuming you're trying to do. **you will need to update your page/UI next...** Here is the completed code, which includes comments on what i've done:

```
public class MVVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Set to Private since we NEVER want MVVM binding to this property becuase it DOES NOT 
    // call the 'OnPropertyChanged' whenever the value is changed 
    private bool _isShowFrame= true;  
    public bool IsShowFrame
    {
        get => _isShowFrame;
        set
        {
            // We check to see if the value has changed, if it hasn't we're done. 
            if (_isShowFrame == value) return;

            // If the value HAS changed, we will save the new value here. 
            _isShowFrame = value;

            // We will now let everyone know that the value has changed! This will update your UI!
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here is a property for the UserName that will update in MVVM - you'll see how i use the same structure, and call the "OnPropertyChanged" whenever the property is changed:

```
    private string _userName; 
    public string UserName
    {
        get => _userName;
        set
        {
            if (_userName == value) return;
            _userName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }
```

### PART 2 - Fixing your Page/Form

Your Page/window **Has two parts** - the XAML code, and the "Code-Behind" which is written in C# (in your case). The **Code-Behind** contains all of the 'events' like when a button is clicked, and other things that you build into it.

You haven't provided much code, so we're going to pretend your XAML Page is named 'MainWindow' - so in Visual Studio, it's called "Main Window.xaml". The C# 'code behind' is called "Main Window.xaml.cs"

XAML:

```
<Entry x:Name="entryName"  TextChanged="entryName_TextChanged"/>
<Frame  BackgroundColor="Gray" Margin="10" x:Name="FramesName" IsVisible="{Binding  IsShowFrame}" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** - Again - You haven't provided much code, so i can't give you an **exact** code-behind. Remember - the 'MainWindow' is a made up page that i'm assuming we're working with. **Change 'MyProgram' in this code with the name of your app/default namespace**

```
public partial class MainWindow : UserControl
{
    MyProgram.MVVM mvvm = new MyProgram.MVVM();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = mvvm;
    }

    protected void entryName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      mvvm.IsShowFrame = false;
    }

}
```

This answer gives you the basics on using MVVM - you've learned how to setup a property, trigger UI updates automatically, and set binding (called DataContext). If you take the time to understand what's going on in this answer - it will REALLY help you.

Once you get this working, i'd suggest reviewing my answer for a similar question: [Binding Viewmodel to View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072024/binding-viewmodel-to-view/60083072#60083072) - this will teach you how to change items from external classes and pages, using MVVM. It might even help you understand what's going on in this question too.

Good Luck!